# How to make PHP session mechanism work correctly after Apache web server configuration

Tags: php, apache

I'm a junior PHP web developer and I don't guess how does PHP sessions mechanism work after Apache web server
module rewriting to make MVC pattern work. Suppose we have 2 physical PHP pages, in both pages we call session_start() 
function and in both pages is printed the same session variable value, in the first page we assign the value to session variable 
returned by rand() function. 
After that when I don't even load the first page, which initializes session variable, the second page after the second reloading
prints session variable value and generates different value after each reloading (in the second page we only try to print session variable value).
When I rollback Apache web server run time configuration module rewriting directives, everything works fine and after loading the second page a new random 
number isn't assigned to session variable in the first PHP page. I noticed that this issue happens when assigning randomly generated values to session 
variables not when asigning fixed values.

Apache web server run time configuration directives:

```
Options -Indexes 

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```